# Agregar fila en DataGridView en Visual Basic

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, vb.net, .net

estoy tratando de crear algo como un tipo de carrito de compras en VB y quiero crear una GridView con los elementos que se van agregando, el problema es que lo hago igual que se haria en c# pero no me muestra los datos.

```
Dim dttDataTable As New DataTable

    dttDataTable.Columns.Add("ID")
    dttDataTable.Rows.Add("52")
    gvCarrito.DataSource = dttDataTable
    gvCarrito.DataBind()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Hay que añadir totals los columnes y valores para las filas.

```
dtDataTable.Columns.Add("nombre")
dtDataTable.Columns.Add("cantidad")
dtDataTable.Columns.Add("precio_cada")
dtDataTable.Columns.Add("precio_entero")

dim entrada = dtDataTable.NewRow()
entrada("nombre") = "Juan"
entrada("cantidad") = 2
entrada("precio_cada") = 5
entrada("precio_entero") = 10
dtDataTable.Rows.Add(entrada)
```

Aquí está un ejemplo:

https://docs.microsoft.com/es-mx/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable?view=net-5.0